# Run a very long query in application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm creating an app that will run a query from text file using C#.

One row of the query looks like:

```
update table1 set value1 = (select valueA from table2 where valueB = 'someValue')
set ...
where value2 = 'anotherValue'
```

Set statements are 17 every on look exactly like the one above and all are in the same update statement.

Reading the file is taking too long the program is not responding. And I even tried executing the query in SSMS - it doesn't not work.

Edit:I have more than 70000 update statement.

And I need the solution in C# not SQL.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express and SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: Get the query plan from SQL Server Management Studio (press "Display Estimated Execution Plan" a few buttons to the right of the "Execute" button) and post the execution plan here.

Comment: Question: you have 17 updates to perform on your database, sequentially. Do you want your application will appear "alive" during that process? Did you try to move that code in a separate thread? Your application may go on with its job (or at least user may interact somehow with a nice progress bar).

Comment: Are table1 and table2 related? Is table1 indexed by value2 and table2 by valueB? You mentioned that query wouldn't work in SSMS - was it taking too long or was there an error?

Comment: how to post ececution plane here ??
post xml??

Comment: why you don't write a c# code to execute these queries? if you are unfamiliar with c# coding ask me and other to give you some useful hint or code. if not, explain the problem more please

Comment: this is what i tried
---
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("");
            string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            connection.Open();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string commandText = sr.ReadLine();
            while (commandText != null)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                commandText = sr.ReadLine(); 
            }            
            sr.Close();
            connection.Close();

Comment: How many rows are there in table1 and table2 and does table1 have a trigger?

Comment: Also, what happens if you only use 1 set-statement in the query: will that go through?

Comment: @Martin no it will not 
i have about 70800 update statement

Answer (score 0):

Provided everything is ok with your indexes and query plans,
have  you tried some table hints (with ...) to check if this comes from a locking problem ?

```
update table1 set value1 = (select valueA from table2 with (nolock) where valueB = 'someValue')
set ...
where value2 = 'anotherValue'
```

Note that, if you are not sure of what is done by the query, running this kind of table hints may introduce some inconsistencies in your database/update result.